# mod_wsgi (Daemon mode) is not reloading the the sourcecode

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've read through [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode), and it seems clear.

I have 2 multi-threaded mod_wsgi processes. Normally I just touch the wsgi script and the source code is reloaded. But periodically, changes aren't reloaded, and the problem persists for a few hours. I don't understand what happens to cause it to stop reloading changes, nor what caused it to start reloading again when I've had the problem in the past.

I've tried killing the mod_wsgi processes, but it made no difference. I cannot restart apache myself.

1. What else can I do to try to force a reload?
2. How can I prevent this from continuing to happen?

Here is the wsgi configuration:

```
    WSGIScriptAlias /ms20 /var/www-dev/wsgi-scripts/ms20.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess ms20 user=glpp group=glab processes=2 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup ms20

    <Directory "/var/www-dev/wsgi-scripts">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did run the tests in the documentation to validate that requests are handled in the daemon process?

Use the display-name option to WSGIDaemonProcess so you can validate using 'ps' that only the mod_wsgi daemon processes are using a lot of memory and not all the Apache 'httpd' processes. It is possible that your VirtualHost configuration is wrong and your WSGI application is running in embedded mode.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the display-name option, and it has seemed extremely clear that requests are handled in Daemon Mode for a few months now. (There are two other virtual hosts on the server that run PHP sites, so the Apache processes are being used for them). The errors (that reference out of date code) look like `[Thu Mar 01 16:06:12 2012] [error] [client ###.###.###.#] mod_wsgi (pid=6649): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www-dev/wsgi-scripts/ms20.wsgi'.` and the pid is one of the two Daemon wsgi processes. I'll add the configuration to my question in a second.

Comment: The threading is also as expected. Should I be convinced, or what else do I do to validate?

Comment: If there is only the one WSGI application, you could try forcing use of a specific sub interpreter to ensure that somehow not splitting requests across more than one, although with that configuration it should be possible. So add 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'.

Comment: Also, in the way you deploy things, is there any way you could have time mismatches on files and old .pyc files in file system appear to be newer than .py files they are supposed to be generated from.

Comment: There will be two applications shortly. It doesn't look like there are any time mismatches (another thing I tried yesterday was removing all of the .pyc files - no affect), and my setup is pretty basic. But as of this morning it's working again, so I'll have to wait and see if it happens again and if I can spot something that's going on. I'll try to contact you directly if I have more problems or have anything helpful to add. Thank you.